# wp wp_register_script function results type parameter missing

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I used the following code

```
wp_register_script('jquery', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.js', false, '',false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

It includes the script as

Here how to add the type parameter as `type="text/javascript"`

Because it creates an error in IE browser

Please help to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Scripts that have been pre-registered using wp_register_script() do not need to be manually enqueued using wp_enqueue_script() if they are listed as a dependency of another script that is enqueued.

```
wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-careers-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-careers-script.js', array( 'jquery', 'my-script' ) );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code. Code only answers is of no value if no knows how it works and how it should be used.

Comment: Scripts that have been pre-registered using wp_register_script() do not need to be manually enqueued using wp_enqueue_script() if they are listed as a dependency of another script that is enqueued.

Comment: This code useful if you want to use ajax other wise you use script tag for ex. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Just remember, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is for child themes, the OP is using a parent theme. You should be using `get_template_directory_uri()` :-)